# C#: Cannot use Controls property from a library that create dynamic objects

Tags: c#, dynamic, controls

I am at the beginning and I want to create a library that can be used in my main Form. The library role is to create dynamic objects (labels) for my Form, but when I compile the project I received this message at this line **this.Controls.Add(genLabel)**:

> *Error    CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Control.Controls'*

If I copy the library contain and put in the form I don't have this error. Could someone explain to me how I should correct the code?

The code from my library:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using mainProgram;

namespace LabelClass
{
    class labelClass
    {
        public void genLabel(string x)
        {
            List<char> bits = new List<char>();
            int i = x.Length - 1;
            int nrbit = 0;

            do
            {
                bits.Add(x[i]);
                i -= 1;
            }
            while (i >= 0);

            i = bits.Count - 1;
            int minus = 0;

            do
            {
                Label genLabel = new Label();
                genLabel.Name = "bits" + Convert.ToString(nrbit);
                genLabel.Text = bits[i] + "";
                genLabel.Size = new Size(50, 20);
                genLabel.Location = new Point(734 - minus, 86);
                minus += 60;
                i -= 1;
                this.Controls.Add(genLabel);
            }
            while (i >= 0);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the code shown would produce that error.  The class shown *has no* member called `Controls`, so there should be an error indicating that instead.  I suspect there's something else going on here that you're not including.

Comment: You class would need to inherit Label : class labelClass : Label.  But it would not work.  I think you want instead of "this" use the form instance.  So you wold need to pass the Form in the parameter list : public void genLabel(Form form, string x).  The use form.Controls.Add(genLabel);

Comment: Thank you for your answers I forgot to include also the using part. I think this is the reason why David cannot see the problem.

Comment: @jdweng: Thank you for your answer, now is works. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

I did like jdweng said and is work. I added a new parameter in genLabel with the type Form and in the main program where I called the method I used "this" keyword.

Library:

```
public void genLabel(Form form, string x)
```

MainProgram:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            saveString = obj.checkStringContainHex(textBox1.Text);
            if(saveString != "Error")
            {
                saveInt = obj.convertHexToDec(saveString);
                saveString = obj.convertDecToBin(saveInt);
                labelClass labelClass = new labelClass();
                labelClass.genLabel(this, saveString);
            }
        }
```